# Make Class - Javascript CodeWars Challenge

Tags: javascript, class

I don't understand what [this problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/make-class/train/javascript) wants us to do.

Instructions say:

---

> I don't really like writing classes like this:

```
function Animal(name,species,age,health,weight,color) {
  this.name = name;
  this.species = species;
  this.age = age;
  this.health = health;
  this.weight = weight;
  this.color = color;
}
```

> Give me the power to create a similar class like this:

```
const Animal = makeClass("name","species","age","health","weight","color")
```

---

As far as I understand, the first code block above is a Constructor function, where, if you wanted to create an instance, you could then do something like:

```
const Animal = new Animal("name","species","age","health","weight","color")
```

So it's asking for us to allow someone to create an instance *without* using the `new` keyword?

It gives us this code to start with:

```
function makeClass(...properties) {

}
```

How can I allow someone to create an instance with this function without using the `new` keyword?

Comment: It's not asking you to be able to create an instance without `new`. It's asking for `const Animal = makeClass("name","species","age","health","weight","color");` to do the same thing as the original code, which is to make Animal a reference to a constructable function. You would still then go on to use `const dog = new Animal(...`.

Comment: I see, so it just wanted us to create a constructor function that creates properties, no matter how many arguments are given. Your solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, as @Paulpro explained in their comment, this does solve the challenge:

```
function makeClass( ...props ) { 
  return function ( ...args ) { 
  props.forEach( (prop, i) => this[prop] = args[i] ) 
  }; 
}
```

Comment: Please give credit to @Paulpro who offered this solution in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function makeClass(){
  let newClass = Object.create(null);

  for(let property of arguments){
    newClass[property] = property;
  }
  return newClass;
}

console.log(makeClass("name","species","age","health","weight","color"));

/*
Returns:
{
name:   "name"
species:"species"
age:    "age"
health: "health"
weight: "weight"
color:  "color"
}
*/
```